React: creating a combobox
Student here, trying to create an app for my thesis, using Laravel, React and Inertia.
I am trying to create a simple, reusable Combobox component. It needs to have an id HTML attribute and it needs to contain an id as a value, so that I can use both in a Laravel controller.
This is what I've got. Problem is that most of the lines of the handleSelect function don't work. (Marked with "does not happen".)
When the user selects an item from the ul, I expect:

the visible input {title}_input to contain item.name -> doesn't happen
the hidden {title}_id to contain item.id -> doesn't happen
the ul to close -> DOES happen



const {useState} = React;

const Combobox = ({}) => {
    const [input, setInput] = useState('')
    const [returnValue, setReturnValue] = useState ('')
    const [showUl, setShowUl] = useState(false)

    //TURN INTO PROPS
        const title = 'test'
        const array = [
            { id: 1, name: 'eins' },
            { id: 2, name: 'zwei' },
            { id: 3, name: 'polizei' },
        ]
    //end of props

    const filteredArray = (
        input
        ? array.filter(item => item.name.toLowerCase().includes(input.toLowerCase()))
        : array
    )

    const handleSelect = (name, id) => {
        setInput(name) // does not happen.
        setReturnValue(id) // does not happen.
        setShowUl(false)
        console.log(`input is now ${input}`) // does not happen.
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <input
                id={`${title}_input`}
                type="text"
                placeholder='choose an option'
                value={input}
                onChange={e => {setInput(e.target.value)}}
                onFocus={() => {setShowUl(true)}}
                onBlur={() => {setShowUl(false)}}
            />
            <input
                id={`${title}_id`}
                type="hidden"
                value={returnValue}
            />
            {showUl &&
                <ul>
                    {filteredArray.map(item => (
                        <li
                            key={item.id}
                            onClick={() => handleSelect(item.name, item.id)}
                        >{item.name}</li>
                    ))}
                </ul>
            }
        </div>
    )
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(
    document.getElementById("root")
).render(
    <Combobox/>
);
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>




If everything in the function "does not happen" then that pretty strongly suggests the function simply isn't being called.  Maybe some styling issue is obscuring it and the element isn't actually receiving the click event?  Maybe something else is failing before that click event is processed?  Can you update this to a [mcve] as a React code snippet which demonstrates the problem?

@David - I have updated my post as requested. As you can see, no (custom) CSS is being applied. Also, it seems that part of the handleSelect function is being executed. I have clarified my post further to reflect this.

It looks like onBlur={() => {setShowUl(false)}} is hiding the <ul> before the click has been processed.  You probably don't want to hide it if the user is clicking on it.


Problem is that most of the lines of the handleSelect function don't work.

The function isn't being called.  So it's really all of the lines of code in that function, and it's not that they "don't work" but rather that they're simply not being invoked in the first place.
This event is occurring first:
onBlur={() => {setShowUl(false)}}

Which is effectively re-rendering the component before that click event is ever processed.  Remove it and the click event works as expected:


const {useState} = React;

const Combobox = ({}) => {
    const [input, setInput] = useState('')
    const [returnValue, setReturnValue] = useState ('')
    const [showUl, setShowUl] = useState(false)

    //TURN INTO PROPS
        const title = 'test'
        const array = [
            { id: 1, name: 'eins' },
            { id: 2, name: 'zwei' },
            { id: 3, name: 'polizei' },
        ]
    //end of props

    const filteredArray = (
        input
        ? array.filter(item => item.name.toLowerCase().includes(input.toLowerCase()))
        : array
    )

    const handleSelect = (name, id) => {
        setInput(name) // does not happen.
        setReturnValue(id) // does not happen.
        setShowUl(false)
        console.log(`input is now ${input}`) // does not happen.
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <input
                id={`${title}_input`}
                type="text"
                placeholder='choose an option'
                value={input}
                onChange={e => {setInput(e.target.value)}}
                onFocus={() => {setShowUl(true)}}
            />
            <input
                id={`${title}_id`}
                type="hidden"
                value={returnValue}
            />
            {showUl &&
                <ul>
                    {filteredArray.map(item => (
                        <li
                            key={item.id}
                            onClick={() => handleSelect(item.name, item.id)}
                        >{item.name}</li>
                    ))}
                </ul>
            }
        </div>
    )
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(
    document.getElementById("root")
).render(
    <Combobox/>
);
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>



To hide the menu is a bit more involved than just an onBlur event for the <input> element.  A tool like this one may be what you're looking for, or perhaps creating your own.  But essentially you'd want to hide the <ul> when clicking anywhere except the <input> or the <ul>.

This is absolutely correct. Based on your last comment to my post, I had fixed the issue by adding a timeout: setTimeout(() => {setShowUl(false)}, 800). After reading your answer, I will be trying a click-away-listener. Thank you!

Try this
 onClick={() => this.handleSelect(item.name, item.id)}

or
onClick={handleSelect(item.name, item.id)}



   


Can you elaborate on why the OP should "try this"?  What was the problem in the original code and how do either of these changes solve that problem?  In the latter change handleSelect would be executed immediately upon rendering the component, rather than when a click occurs.
